# Proving $ \sum _{k=0} ^m \binom nk \binom{n-k}{m-k} = 2^m \binom {n}{m}$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Give an algebraic and a combinatorial proof for the following identity:
>
> $$ \sum _{k=0} ^m \binom nk \binom{n-k}{m-k} = 2^m \binom {n}{m}.$$
>
> For the combinatorial argument, use the analogy of $n$ party guests, where $m$ of them describe themselves as either vegetarian or vegan (but not both).

After proving the identity using algebraic transformations, I'm unable to find a combinatorial argument for it. For the right hand side, if we multiply $\binom nm $ by $2^n$, we get the Pascal-triangle but with each row multiplied by $2^n$, but here we're multiplying by $2^m$. What does this mean? How does the analogy with the party guests work? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not the best analogy, since it requires us to assume that we can actually **choose** which guests are vegan and which are vegetarian, but I’ll go ahead and use it.

We can first choose $m$ guests to be the vegetarians and vegans; this can be done in $\binom{n}m$ ways. Once they are chosen, we can pick some subset of them to be the vegans; this can be done in $2^m$ ways, since there are $2^m$ subsets of an $m$-element set. Thus, the righthand side does indeed count the ways to choose $m$ of the guests and split them into vegans and vegetarians.

Alternatively, we could first choose $k$ guests to be vegan, where $0\le k\le m$, and then we could choose $m-k$ of the remaining $n-k$ guests to be vegetarians. Thus, there are $\binom{n}k\binom{n-k}{m-k}$ ways to choose $k$ vegans and $m-k$ vegetarians. If we sum over all values of $k$ from $0$ through $m$, this gives us every possible way of choosing $m$ guests and splitting them into vegans and vegetarians, so the lefthand side counts the same thing as the righthand side.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $m$ people from a set of $n$ people and these $m$ people will be vegan or vegeterian This is the RHS.

Choose $\color{red}{k}$ people from $n$ and they will be vegan, now choose $\color{blue}{m-k}$ people from the remaining $n-k$ peoples they will be vegetarian Let $k$ range over $0$ to $m$. This is the LHS.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward calculation:  $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}=\frac{n!(n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!(n-m)!(m-k)!}\times\frac{m!}{m!}=\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}$

Now take the sum over $k$, i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}=2^m$.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a party of $n$ where $m$ guests have binary preferences, you can:

1. Select $m$ guests first, and then choose a preference for every one of them.
2. Or you can choose how many vegetarians you have and assign them. After that assign to the non-vegetarian guests the left number of vegan options.