# Prove combinatorically, that for $n \geq m$: $\sum_{k=0}^m \dbinom{n}{k} \dbinom{n-k}{m-k}= 2^m \dbinom{n}{m}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Prove combinatorically, that for $n \geq m$:
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^m \dbinom{n}{k} \dbinom{n-k}{m-k}= 2^m \dbinom{n}{m}$$

The right hand side tells that us the number of ways we can pick either white or black $m$ balls from a total of $n$ balls. But I'm not sure what the connection between that and the left hand side is.

Comment: This was asked earlier today: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713102/proving-sum-k-0-m-binom-nk-binomn-km-k-2m-binom-nm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $ \sum _{k=0} ^m \binom nk \binom{n-k}{m-k} = 2^m \binom {n}{m}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713102/proving-sum-k-0-m-binom-nk-binomn-km-k-2m-binom-nm)